# responds_to_parent in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How I will use responds_to_parent plug in rails 3. I had used it in rails 2.3.5. At that time there was no errors. But when I shifted to rails 3 its showing the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `erase_redirect_results'.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/itkin/respond_to_parent

Comment: This won't work in Rails 3.1 because ActionView::Helpers::PrototypeHelper has been removed, as @OlivierGrimard says in another comment.  You can get it back with the prototype-rails gem, but since Rails 3.1 comes with jquery as the default, using both can cause conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Here is implementation for rails ~> 3.2
https://github.com/Gonzih/respond_to_parent

Comment: Works for me on Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3.1 'responds_to_parents' doesn't works because it use the library 'PrototypeHelper' and this library has been removed in 3.1. 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper

In rails >3.0, you can always replace 'responds_to_parent' by 'remotipart'.
[os.alfajango.com/remotipart/](http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart/)
https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Answer (score 1):

Like report on his issue tracker : http://github.com/markcatley/responds_to_parent/issues#issue/1

This plugin is not Rails 3 compatible.

You have 4 choices :

- Downgrade to rails 2 and still using this plugin
- Hack this plugin to made it compatible to Rails 3
- Wait this plugin to be compatible to Rails 3
- Unsused this plugin

Answer (score -1):

rails 3.0 support is fixed in version 1.1.0, not sure about 3.1+